# Validate name in form with accents jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

So I have to validate the name in a form, a few of validations are:

- Name must be 5-50 characters
- Name must validate accents = áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ
- Name must validate spaces

I was trying to use a regular expression like this:

```
 /^(?=.{5,50}$)\p{L}*(?: \p{L}+)*?/;
```

But javascript doesn't allow unicode expressions, I cannot use plugins as XRegExp, also I have tried:

```
    /^[a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]+$/i
```

and

```
    /^[A-Za-z-áéíóú]+$/
```

Any help?

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: 5-50 chars or 5-80 chars?

Comment: Thank you! let me correct it :)

Comment: Can you give a case for which `/^[a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]+$/i` gives incorrect results? I assume you really wanted `/^[a-z\u00E0-\u00FC ]{5,50}$/i` to match your other requirements of course -- was that the only problem? Or  is the problem that the range `\u00E0-\u00FC` includes some characters you don't want? (If so, are you simply looking for the specific unicode values for the accent characters?)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiarized with this sort of validation I started to study javascript a week ago, what I tried to do is validate names like: Juan Pérez, juan pérez, Lucía Álvarez etc... I'm so sorry if I'm not specific enough, I tried your espressions but it doesn't seem to work, it gives no match with the examples that I just gave you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following *regex* :

```
[a-z \u00E0-\u00FC]{5,50}
```

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ishF0j/1)**

**JavaScript**

```js
var names = ['áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ', 'adádÚ', 'abcd', 'de fg'];
names.forEach(function(e) {
  var valid = 'Validating "' + e + '"... | ' + /[a-z \u00E0-\u00FC]{5,50}/i.test(e);
  console.log(valid);
});
```

Comment: This worked! just a little question, what can I add in order to validate simple names like josé and pepe without a space at the end?

Comment: If you see when you test  'abcd' it comes as false.

Comment: @CarmenAmaro its bcoz `abcd` is not 5 char. you wanna match names like `carmen jose`  or just `jose`?

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry, this is the perfect answer, thank you so much!